# How to implement the Pause action for the android VideoView?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-ndk, android-videoview, android-video-player

In my Application i am going to Play the VideoView.

I am not using the Media Controller for variour option like Play, Pause and Stop.

Instead of that i am Using Single Button to Use Play and Pause Functionality.

I have Implement like Below Code:

```
case R.id.playVideoBtn:
        if(myVideoView.isPlaying()){
            myVideoView.pause();
        }else{

            //MediaController ctlr=new MediaController(this);
        //  ctlr.setMediaPlayer(myVideoView);
            //myVideoView.setMediaController(ctlr);

            myVideoView.start();
        }


        break;
```

Now i am wonder about how to implement the Pause functionality for the same Button Click.

Please help me for it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From [VideoView.java](http://android.git.kernel.org/?p=platform/frameworks/base.git;a=blob;f=core/java/android/widget/VideoView.java) I found...

```
start() goes with pause(), but resume() goes with suspend() (the latter pair causing the screen to blank out).
```

And for your solution look at this example [Playing Video](http://eagle.phys.utk.edu/guidry/android/playingVideo.html)